# Show a convolution of distributions ε-close to min-entropy k is ε^t-close to min-entropy k

Tags: probability-distributions, fourier-analysis, entropy, convolution

Assume $X_1,...,X_t$ are independent distributions on $\mathbb{Z}_2^n$ s.t. each $X_i$ is $\epsilon$-close to min-entropy $k$; i.e. there exist distributions $Y_1,...,Y_t$ on $\mathbb{Z}_2^n$ s.t:
$$ \forall i: \frac{1}{2}\sum_{x\in\mathbb{Z}_2^n}|X_i(x)-Y_i(x)|\leq\epsilon $$
and:
$$ \forall i: H_\infty(Y_i)\geq k $$
where $H_\infty(Y_i)=\min_{x\in\mathbb{Z}_2^n}\{-\log_2(Y_i(x))\}$ is the min-entropy of $Y_i$.

Define $X=\sum_{i=1}^t X_i$ as the distribution corresponding to the *convolution* of $X_1,...,X_t$:
$$ X(x)=\sum_{\substack{x_1,...,x_t\in\mathbb{Z}_2^n\\x_1\oplus...\oplus x_t=x}}\prod_{i=1}^t X_i(x_i) $$
How do I show that $X$ is $\epsilon^t$-close to min-entropy $k$?